# Performing `top_n`-like operations on tibbles with intersecting groups

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, greatest-n-per-group, tibble

I'm trying to write an R script to perform the following task. I have two tibbles:

```
library(dplyr); library(magrittr)

(
tibs <- list(
        top = tibble(
                letter = c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4)), 
                number = c(rep(1,2), rep(2,2)) %>% rep(2),
                element = c("x","y","z","w","x","y","z","w"),
                score = 1:8
                ) %>% group_by(letter,number),
        bottom = tibble(
                letter = c(rep("A",2),rep("B",2)),
                element = c("p","q","y","z"),
                score = c(2.5,3.5, 4,5.5)
                ) %>% group_by(letter)
        )
)

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   letter, number [4]
  letter number element score
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>   <int>
1 A           1 x           1
2 A           1 y           2
3 A           2 z           3
4 A           2 w           4
5 B           1 x           5
6 B           1 y           6
7 B           2 z           7
8 B           2 w           8

$bottom
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   letter [2]
  letter element score
  <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>
1 A      p         2.5
2 A      q         3.5
3 B      y         4  
4 B      z         5.5
```

For each group `Xn` of the top-level tibble, defined by letter (`X` = "A" or "B") and number (`n` = 1 or 2), I would like to select the two lowest scoring elements, among those that appear in group `Xn` of the top-level tibble or in group `X` of the lower level tibble. If an element appears both in the top- and lower-level tibble, it's score is taken from the `top` tibble.

So, in this example, I'm expecting to get `x,y` for group `A1`, `p,z` for group `A2`, `x,z` for group `B1` and `y,z` for group `B2`.

I have to perform this kind of operation on (top-level) tibbles having up to a million different groups (at top level), and a few entries in each group. I would like to obtain a **fast** and possibly **readable** solution, within dplyr or not.

---

My solution so far returns the expected output, but is particularly unsatisfying from the efficiency point of view:

```
summarizer <- function(letter, element, score, bottom){
        bottom %<>% filter(letter == !!letter[1], !(element %in% !!element))
        order(c(score, bottom$score)) %>%
                c(element, bottom$element)[.] %>%
                head(2) %>%
                paste0(collapse = " ")
}


tibs$top %>% summarise(preds = summarizer(letter, element, score, 
                                          tibs$bottom)
                       )


# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   letter [2]
  letter number preds
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
1 A           1 x y  
2 A           2 p z  
3 B           1 x z  
4 B           2 y z
```

In particular, with a large number of groups, the big bottleneck is the pipe-assignment `%<>%` in my function `summarizer`, which however I can't see how to avoid.

---

I have the following questions related to the above:

1. `dplyr`'s group_by groups are, by construction, never intersecting. Is there a way (within dplyr or not) to group data.frames in such a way that rows can belong to more than one group?
2. If not, my task could be solved by creating duplicates of the elements belonging to more groups and labeling them appropriately. How would you do this *fastly*?
3. Do you see any other *fast* (and possibly readable) solution to the above problem?

Comment: You say that you want "to select the two highest scoring elements", so either you (1) consider a lower score value as 'better' or 'higher' or your (2) `summarizer` selects the wrong elements, because in group `A 1` for example `p` and `q` have higher scores than `x` and `y`.

Comment: @TimTeaFan, it's option 1, thanks. Edited

Comment: Would you consider a data.table solution?

Comment: @chinsoon12 was actually wondering if that could help.  I have no experience with data.table, if you have any idea and want to share I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(top)
setDT(bottom)

#get unique groups
g = unique(top[,.(letter, number)])

#creating duplicates for each letter in bottom for each group using a left join on letter
b = bottom[g, on=.(letter)]

#If an element appears both in the top- and lower-level tibble, it's score is taken from the top tibble.
#use an update join to lookup the scores from top tibble
b[top, on=.(letter, number, element), score := i.score]

#bind_rows and remove identical rows
rowsbind = rbindlist(list(top, b), use.names=TRUE)
both = unique(rowsbind, by=c("letter", "number", "element"))

#order and subset
setorder(both, letter, number, score)
both[rowid(letter, number) <= 2L]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
top = data.table(
    letter = c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4)), 
    number = rep(c(rep(1,2), rep(2,2)), 2),
    element = c("x","y","z","w","x","y","z","w"),
    score = as.double(1:8)
)
bottom = data.table(
    letter = c(rep("A",2),rep("B",2)),
    element = c("p","q","y","z"),
    score = c(2.5,3.5, 4,5.5)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, using left joins was the hint I was needing. I'll add as a separate answer the implementation in dplyr.

Answer (score 1):

Same strategy as in the accepted answer, but using dplyr.

```
top1 <- bind_rows(bottom %>% left_join(top %>% select(letter, number) %>% unique),
                  top,
                  .id = "id") %>%
        group_by(letter, number, element) %>% top_n(1, wt = id) %>% ungroup %>% 
        group_by(letter, number) %>%
        mutate(rank = rank(score, ties.method = "first")) %>%
        filter(rank <= 2) %>%
        select(letter, number, element, score)
```

Comment: In terms of performance I would be interested in how the three approaches differ when applied to your real data. I rewrote your first approach in dplyr using `nest_by` and `bind_rows`/`filter` and it was far worse performance-wise than your original approach. It was like 8x slower (but the readability was great ;). My guess is, that your first approach is quite performant, since you mostly use vector operations (and not `data.frame`s). I expect this `dplyr` solution to be slower, and the `data.table` answer to be the fastest.

Comment: Dear, @TimTeaFan, I haven't implemented yet the data.table solution proposed @chinsoon12 on my actual data, as all my previous code was written using `dplyr`. I hope to get the time to experiment a little bit with it in the next days, since as you say it is probably going to perform better than `dplyr`. Concerning the two approaches in `dplyr`: consider that my `top` tibble has ~900k groups (of the `Xn` kind) and my `bottom` tibble has ~30k groups (of the `X` kind), both with four entries in each group. Performing the above operations took about 70 mins with my former implementation, [...]

Comment: [...] and about 4 minutes with the one proposed in this answer. The big improvement appears to come from avoiding the filtering in my summarizer function, as in: `bottom %<>% filter(letter == !!letter[1], !(element %in% !!element))` . This causes huge memory allocations - dellocations (I haven't been able to run `profvis` on this dataset... on a reduced dataset I had something like ~0.5 TB of allocated/deallocated memory). If I find some time in the next few days, I will upload my data and some benchmarks. Thanks for your interest!